# Solving project Euler 25 in a functional manner using Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, out-of-memory

I am currently using Project Euler to learn Scala. 
I am stuck on problem 25 with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception.

Here is the question:

> What is the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits?

What I have come up with:

```scala
def fibonacciIndex(numOfDigits: Int): Option[Int] = {
  lazy val fibs: LazyList[Int] = 0 #:: fibs.scanLeft(1)(_ + _)
  fibs.find(_.toString.length == numOfDigits)
}
```

I am trying to do this in a purely functional way. 
Has anyone got some suggestions to improve the memory usage?

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: I was overflowing the `Int` type. Solved like so:

```scala
def fibonacciIndex(numOfDigits: Int): Int = {
    lazy val bigFibs: LazyList[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: bigFibs.scanLeft(BigInt(1))(_ + _)
    bigFibs.indexWhere(_.toString.length == numOfDigits)
}
```

Comment: That should be fine AFAIK, so I guess the problem is related to using `Int` instead of something like `BigDecimal` but not sure why that would produce that error. / Ah, also, you want `indexOf` instead of `find`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez changing to `BigInt` and using `indexWhere` solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I would advice to try doing these problems in Haskell. You won't have any problems with OutOfMemory issues there, Haskell can work with huge numbers, and is by default a lazy and pure functional language, so it fits perfectly your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run your program in parts.

```
lazy val fibs: LazyList[Int] = 0 #:: fibs.scanLeft(1)(_ + _)
fibs.take(100).foreach(println)
```

It prints:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
9227465
14930352
24157817
39088169
63245986
102334155
165580141
267914296
433494437
701408733
1134903170
1836311903
-1323752223
512559680
-811192543
-298632863
-1109825406
-1408458269
1776683621
368225352
2144908973
-1781832971
363076002
-1418756969
-1055680967
1820529360
764848393
-1709589543
-944741150
1640636603
695895453
-1958435240
-1262539787
1073992269
-188547518
885444751
696897233
1582341984
-2015728079
-433386095
1845853122
1412467027
-1036647147
375819880
-660827267
-285007387
-945834654
-1230842041
2118290601
887448560
-1289228135
-401779575
-1691007710
-2092787285
511172301
-1581614984
-1070442683
1642909629
572466946
-2079590721
-1507123775
708252800
-798870975
-90618175
-889489150
```

As you can see integer overflows, and so it never outputs more than certain number of digits (11 I think including `-`). So it keep in computing next value.

Additionally `LazyList` remembers each value that it computed. It is lazy but memoizes. So each new number that is computed here

```
fibs.find(_.toString.length == numOfDigits)
```

is also remembered. It continues until you run out of memory.

To fix that you should replace `LazyList` with e.g. `Iterator` or `Iterable` and store numbers as `BigInt`s.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had thought of overflow errors but did not follow through. Changing to `BigInt`s and using `indexWhere` solved my issue.

Comment: I thought `LazyList` wouldn't memonize if the reference was not preserved.

Comment: If you won't preserve it, then yes, you can pretty mach garbage collect all "head" before your currently computed value. But here OP had `lazy val fibs: LazyList[Int]` inside a method, so it was preserving all values until the method returned (and in ops case it didn't return before OOM).

Comment: Now that I think, doing `( 0 #:: fibs.scanLeft(1)(_ + _) ).find(_.toString.length == numOfDigits)` would already prevent OOM, although for certain large enough inputs, this would never return due to overflow. And keeping the`LazyList` `val` while having `BigInt` only moves away the moment when you OOM, but doesn't prevent it - you still memoize the values, but it requires more digits to expand this lazy list enough.